# Create a multiindex DataFrame from existing delimited column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like the following

```
           A_value A_avg B_value B_avg
date
2020-01-01       1     2      3      4
2020-02-01       5     6      7      8
```

and my goal is to create a multiindex Dataframe that looks like that:

```
                 A            B
                 value avg    value  avg
date
2020-01-01       1     2      3      4
2020-02-01       5     6      7      8
```

So the part of the column name before the '-' should be the first level of the column index and the part afterwards the second level. The first part is unstructured, the second is always the same (4 endings).

I tried to solve it with `pd.wide_to_long()` but I think that is the wrong path, as I don't want to change the df itself. The real df is much larger, so creating it manually is not an option. I'm stuck here and did not find a solution.

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.str.split("_",expand=True)` ?

Comment: @anky beat me to it :)

Comment: Wow that was quick. That solves my problem. Do you create an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the columns by the delimier and expand to create Multiindex:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split("_",expand=True)
```